# Reading image using datareader class through socket stream

Tags: android, windows, sockets

i am creating an applicaiton in Windows mobile and on Android to establish a data transfer between them through socket stream. i finished coding in Android. i converted the image into byte array in android and send it stream.

i do not know how to read it in DataReader class in Windows 10 mobile. if any good examples are there, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This is the link for MSFT UWP samples having many code samples which will be helpful.
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DataReaderWriter

code snippet for  DataReader i used:

```
var reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
while (true)
{
 uint readLength = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
if (readLength < sizeof(uint))
{
break;
}
uint currentLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
readLength = await reader.LoadAsync(currentLength);
if (readLength < currentLength)
{
break;
}
string message = reader.ReadString(currentLength);
}

reader.DetachStream();
```

However, do check at android end since it is different than the normal read and write of stream. Data reader expects the length of message before the message. Make sure to check for the endiannes too. here is the snippet i used in C# which might be useful.

```
try
{
    int len = data.Length;
    byte[] lenByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);
                if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                {
                    Array.Reverse(lenByte);
                }           
               foreach (byte b in lenByte)
                { outStream.WriteByte(b); }

               foreach (byte b in data) outStream.WriteByte(b);
                 Console.WriteLine("Message sent");
                }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(e.Message) ;
            }
```